# Spark: program to find missing numbers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's assume we have a list of numbers like this:.

```
lst = [1,2,4,5,9,10]
```

How would I write Spark program to find out the missing numbers in that list. The program should return: 3,6,7,8.

I tried with accumulator, dint work out.

Comment: can share your solution which was not working and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Spark is not the best option for problems where you depend on looking at other rows while computing each row. Spark is best when you can process each item without depending on the others, so it can parallelize efficiently.

Comment: @Daniel, I also knew so but I was asked to implement it in an interview. I told them the solution with accumulator and they accepted it . Later I tried to implement it at home and it didn't work out as accumulator can only be used to update values by different tasks where the update operation is associative, not to access the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it if you're not too worried about having an optimal solution is to first broadcast the data you have, then parallelize a collection containing all the elements and filter that based on the broadcasted data.

Something like

```
lst = [1,2,4,5,9,10]  
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(lst)

all_elems = sc.parallelize([i+1 for i in range(10)])
all_elems.filter(lambda x: x not in broadcastVar.value)
```

If you're looking for something that just works with small amounts of data then this is fine. If you have a lot of data then this approach is bad and shouldn't be used.

If a better solution is needed then I would do the following

1. Essentially partition the data, using RDDs you can do a map that outputs (parition, number). You can write a small function to get the partition number for each number. So for example if you have 2 executors after this map you would have something like [(1-5, 1), (1-5, 2), (1-5, 4), (1-5, 5), (6-10, 9), (6-10, 10)]
2. Group by key, so now we have [(1-5, [1,2,4,5]), (6-10, [9,10])]
3. Map where you iterate over the range specified by key, compare with the elements in values and return the list of elements that are not present.

You can then write the results or collect or whatever you want to do with them. One thing of note is that for example, if I had used 5 executors, so the keys would've been 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10, the key 7-8 wouldn't have any elements. To avoid this one option is to union the rdd before group by key with something like [(1-2, -1), (3-4, -1), (5-6, -1), (7-8, -1), (9-10, -1)]. If you have a lot of data then the overhead added by this is very small compared to the whole job.

There's a number of things wrong with this samplecode but consider it just as proof of concept.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.spark_project.guava.collect.Lists;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark-missing-nr").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
    Integer[] lst = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10 };
    JavaRDD<Integer> lstRDD = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(lst));

    // Partition the data by whether number is smaller/equal or larger than
    // 5
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> groupableRDD = lstRDD.mapToPair(i -> {
        String group = i <= 5 ? "1-5" : "6-10";
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(group, i);
    });
    // Group by key
    JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Integer>> groupedRDD = groupableRDD.groupByKey();

    // so now we have [(1-5,[1, 2, 4, 5]), (6-10,[9, 10])]
    System.out.println(groupedRDD.collect());

    // map where you iterate over range specified by key
    JavaRDD<List<Integer>> missingValuesLists = groupedRDD.map(t -> {
        Integer from = new Integer(t._1().split("-")[0]);
        Integer to = new Integer(t._1().split("-")[1]);

        List<Integer> valuesList = Lists.newArrayList(t._2());
        List<Integer> missingValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // iterate over range specified by key
        for (int i = from; i < to + 1; i++) {
            if (!valuesList.contains(i)) {
                missingValues.add(i);
            }
        }
        return missingValues;
    });
    // outputs [[3], [6, 7, 8]]
    System.out.println(missingValuesLists.collect());
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I am afraid I have to do it with a list having around one billion numbers.

Comment: Hi Ossu54, can you please provide code sample for this if possible?

Comment: I added some samplecode in Java, hope that's alright.

Comment: I tried in Scala and it worked handsomely. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an RDD with the full range, using `sc.range`, then using the [`subtract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.subtract) function:

```py
lst = sc.parallelize([1,2,4,5,9,10])
max_value = lst.max()
full_data = sc.range(1, max_value)
missing_values = full_data.subtract(lst)
```

You can avoid calling `max()` if you know beforehand the size of the full list.

Comment: Sorry Daniel for late reply (I have been too busy). I tried and it works but it cannot be considered as optimal solution if we are dealing with billions of numbers, we can't have one more list of that huge data alongside to process. Anyway thanks for the solution and I liked the subtraction part :) It's the simplest approach.